# JQuery's Addition Assignment (+=) does not work on iOS?

Tags: jquery, ios

I'm trying to add a class on my JSDatepicker Calendar using addition assignment, since i have 2 functions that checks dates. One for holidays, and one for events. However, only the holiday part works on iOS, and not the events. It works on Android and Web though, and I have tried inspecting my website thru Web Inspector and verified that the script is indeed the problem area, not my CSS or the cache. Here's the code for the Events/Holidays class adder (JQ):

```
function my_check(in_date) {

    // Get Events
    var eventsAPI = baseurl + '/wp-json/wp/v2/events/?per_page=100';
    // console.log("ready");
    var highlight = eventDates[in_date];

    var cal_class = '';
    if (highlight) {
        cal_class += "event-active "; //This does not apply on IOS devices
        // return [true, cal_class, name];
    } else {
        cal_class += "no-event ";
        // return [true, cal_class, name];
    }


    // This entire part works.
    var datestring = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', in_date);
    for (i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {

        var name = holidayName[holidays.indexOf(datestring)];
        if (holidays.indexOf(datestring) != -1) {
            cal_class += "notav ";
            return [true, cal_class, name];
        } else {
            return [true, cal_class, name];
        }
    }
    return [true, cal_class, name];


}
```

Here's also my CSS for this part for additional reference:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar td.event-active a {
font-family: 'Montserrat Bold' !important;
font-weight: 900 !important;
color: #000 !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar td.notav a {
    color: red;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Bold';
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can not see any declaration of baseurl in the function

Comment: It's declared globally on the upper portion of the script. I use it for a lot of other functions.